# Sitecore Workbox Extend "Enter a Comment" popup

Tags: sitecore

In Sitecore workbox commands we can set "Suppress Comment" checkbox unchecked and when that particular workbox action is executed it would ask for a comment in a popup. In that I want to let user know that typing a comment is mandatory by showing some custom text. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a blog post about making comment mandatory while rejecting an item. You can easily use it for your purposes as well:

[Sitecore workflows – Comment if you reject something!](http://www.cognifide.com/blogs/sitecore/sitecore-workflows-mandatory-comment-for-reject-command/)

If you need to display the message before user tries to execute workflow command you can override the Sitecore `Workbox.xml` control and in its code behind override the `Comment` method and change `"Enter a comment:"` to whatever you want. The original method code is:

```c#
public void Comment(ClientPipelineArgs args)
{
  Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) args, "args");
  if (!args.IsPostBack)
  {
    Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.Input("Enter a comment:", string.Empty);
    args.WaitForPostBack();
  }
  else if (args.Result.Length > 2000)
  {
    Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.ShowError(new Exception(string.Format("The comment is too long.\n\nYou have entered {0} characters.\nA comment cannot contain more than 2000 characters.", (object) args.Result.Length)));
    Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.Input("Enter a comment:", string.Empty);
    args.WaitForPostBack();
  }
  else
  {
    if (args.Result == null || !(args.Result != "null") || !(args.Result != "undefined"))
      return;
    IWorkflowProvider workflowProvider = Context.ContentDatabase.WorkflowProvider;
    if (workflowProvider == null)
      return;
    IWorkflow workflow = workflowProvider.GetWorkflow(Context.ClientPage.ServerProperties["workflowid"] as string);
    if (workflow == null)
      return;
    Item obj = Context.ContentDatabase.Items[(Context.ClientPage.ServerProperties["id"] ?? (object) string.Empty).ToString(), Language.Parse(Context.ClientPage.ServerProperties["language"] as string), Sitecore.Data.Version.Parse(Context.ClientPage.ServerProperties["version"] as string)];
    if (obj == null)
      return;
    try
    {
      workflow.Execute(Context.ClientPage.ServerProperties["command"] as string, obj, args.Result, true, new object[0]);
    }
    catch (WorkflowStateMissingException ex)
    {
      SheerResponse.Alert("One or more items could not be processed because their workflow state does not specify the next step.", new string[0]);
    }
    UrlString urlString = new UrlString(WebUtil.GetRawUrl());
    urlString["reload"] = "1";
    Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.SetLocation(urlString.ToString());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Maras. We are actually doing the exact same thing. But the client wants to advice users before hand because the warning message comes in a separate popup.

Comment: @KasunJayasinghe I've updated my answer. Does it answer your question now?

Comment: Yes Maras, It fully answers my question. Really appreciate this.